# Error - ScriptHalted while installing Sitecore XC 9.1.0

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

I'm running into the following error when I try to install Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.1.0. 
Previously, I had an error stating that "Services are not available at this time".
Restarting my Sitecore services fixed my issue. But this time, I have tried the installation with a fresh instance of XP but no luck. My SOLR is up and running and all the required services are also running. I have no clue what is causing this error.
Please help me out in finding out how to resolve this error.

[image]

Comment: check commerce engine service logs, is there any error?